# css3 mobile swipe - how to do it?

Tags: css

Building a mobile page with horisontal swipe-support,
I want to use css3 and don't get the hang of it.

Let's say i have a view with a potentail additional view on the right side,
I guess it's initial state would be to hide the right div, but then?

How should the transition be performed?
(I've read [Swipe Animation in CSS3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7141233/swipe-animation-in-css3) but still in the blue..)

Also, how to guarantee 100% widths of the divs?

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="initial" style="width:100%;float:left;">
    initial content
  </div>
  <div id="next" class="hide" style="width:100%;float:left;">
    additional content on request
  </div>
```

regards,
//t

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS3 isn't required for a swipe motion on a mobile site. What is required is a Javascript library that will recognize the live touch events. Try searching for JQuery samples of touchstart touchmove touchend or you could check out the http://jqtouch.com/ library.

Comment: yes, I use zepto.js to catch the trigger and working fine. The question is about the anim, as in github code swipes.

Comment: The js library you are using is an important fact that was not noted. Can you post a link to your code so we can replicate your issue?